# Spring Boot, How to send JSON data to a actual web-api and fetch JSON response

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot Web Application. I have a link to an actual working web API. "www.testexample.com/api/login" for example.

This API needs a couple **post-parameters** written as JSON. For example:

```
{
"​email​"​:​​ ​​"test@test.com"
"​password​"​:​​ ​​"123ABC"
}
```

The API returns **responses** after sending the JSON values above.

```
{
"token​"​:​"123456789"​,
"status​"​:​​ ​​"APPROVED"
}
```

Doing these on Postman is easy but how to transfer this logic to a web application?

So in Spring Boot:

- How can I post JSON values to this API link?
- How do I get the response JSON data if I use just "POST" method?
- Also how can I display these response parameters back on screen?

Can you please help and give me the sample codes or just a simple idea? Or an informative link would do too!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the client-side you may simulate a normal form submission to your login url via ajax. For example, in jQuery

```html
    <form id="loginForm">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Emai</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="login" onclick="Login()"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       var Login = function(){
         $.ajax({
            url: "api/v1/login",// your api url
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
              console.log(result);//your API response.
            }
         });
       }
    </script>
```

Comment: Getting an error :( Failed to load "mycustomurl": No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500. @sudhir When I try to fix it, it gets even complicated. Do you happen to know how can I fix this?

Comment: Ran this command "chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security". Works good now but I wonder will it work on -for example- Heroku just the way it is? Also thank you for your answer, you're the best! I want to ask you another question if I may. I need to save the "token" and use it as a header parameter for other calls that I will make. I would be so happy if you can tell me how to do those two things.